# How to round up or down a number using DecimalPipe in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How to round up or down a number using `DecimalPipe` in Angular
I think, `DecimalPipe` will round a number by default, like:

```
 Rounding({{value | number:'1.0-2'}})
 1.234 => 1.23
 1.235 => 1.24
```

In my case, I'd like to round up/down a number, like:

```
 Rounding up({{value | number:'1.0-2'}})
 1.234 => 1.24
 1.235 => 1.24

 Rounding down({{value | number:'1.0-2'}})
 1.234 => 1.23
 1.235 => 1.23
```

How can I achieve this directly using `DecimalPipe`?

Comment: Now my downvote, but why not just use base JavaScript's `floor()` and `ceil()` functions inside your controller?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Since angular provides the pipe to format a number as text, I think it's a good idea to handle the fractions together in the way we want.

Comment: It looks like the [`DecimalPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe) doesn't have this option, you can check the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.3/packages/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L61-L96) if you want. I think @TimBiegeleisen suggested a good solution if he wants to post it as an answer - or you could create a custom pipe of your own to do this.

Comment: You can build your own pipe: [like here](http://blog.bastien-donjon.fr/round-number-angular-2-pipe/)

Comment: just add/less .005 to your number before pipe

Answer (score 5):

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

enum Direction {
    UP = 'up',
    DOWN = 'down'
}

@Pipe({name: 'toFixed'})
export class ToFixedPipe implements PipeTransform {
    /**
     *
     * @param value - some number
     * @param digits - number of digits after the decimal point
     * @param dir - round up or down (floor/ceil)
     * @returns {string} formatted number with a fixed number of digits after the decimal point
     */
    transform(value: number, digits: number = 0, dir: Direction = Direction.DOWN): number {
        const round = dir === Direction.DOWN ? Math.floor : Math.ceil;
        return round(value * (10 ** digits)) / (10 ** digits);
    }
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#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-HAALJMj6ujFY65RVOfV2CXHcSQDXTE0maEMuTXTWagwIARjNgyGhpIaTSHTRjeb92OwrSxd0vl8QA)

Usage:

Rounding up `{{value | toFixed:2:"up"}}`

1.234 => 1.24

1.235 => 1.24

Rounding down `{{value | toFixed:2:"down"}}`

1.234 => 1.23

1.235 => 1.23

Answer (score 0):

Try Decimal JS:

```
import Decimal from "decimal.js";

let r: Decimal.Rounding = Decimal.ROUND_DOWN;
let c: Decimal.Configuration = {rounding: r };
Decimal.set(c);
let v: Decimal.Value = "12345.6789";
let d: Decimal = new Decimal(v);

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <div>
    ${d.toFixed(3)}
  </div>`
```