# Which Angular Pipe to round number AND cut out its decimals?

Tags: angular, typescript, formatting, pipe

`myNumber` is a number like '2.74' and I want to display it in HTML via interpolation like this:

```
<div> {{ myNumber | myCurrencyEuroPipe }} </div>
```

But I want to round the number to the whole number AND then not display any decimals. So e.g. from '2.74' to '3'. How can I achieve this, ideally with angular pipes? I already use a custom `myCurrencyEuroPipe` just to display an € at the end. Could you provide an example if Angular has its own pipes for this, or is a custom one necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round up or down a number using DecimalPipe in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540552/how-to-round-up-or-down-a-number-using-decimalpipe-in-angular)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'myCurrencyEuro'
})
export class MyCurrencyEuroPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): string {
    return Number(value).toFixed() + '€';
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `myCurrencyEuroPipe` add this piece of code to make it work:

```
transform (value: number) {
      let result = value % 2 >= 0.5 ? Math.ceil(value) : Math.floor(value);
      // now pass this result to add the currency symbol.
}
```